# How to login a user using firebase authentication

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

I'm currently using `firebase-admin` to create a  web Dashboard with `node.js` as a backend which will have multiple users and those users have user specific data in my database, note that I need them to be able to delete or add stuff to the database as well, I've managed to add new users to `Autentication` using `firebase.auth().createUser()` programmatically, but how would one go about logging in a user, and then from there controlling which `uid` is logged in and displaying his data (giving him access to the correct data, obviously don't want him messing with someone elses data).

I know this might seem like a really newbie question, and it probably is,  but firebase docs always get me confused for some reason. Any tips? I'd greatly appreciate.

Any questions don't hesitate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To login a new user, try this:

`firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)`

this returns a `Firebase.Promise` which you can use to track the operation progress. If successful, it will return the corresponding `Firebase.User` object.

From there, the logged-in user will also be available in the `firebase.auth().currentUser` property. You can then use the user's `uid` property as a key for his JSON branch on the database.

Comment: Ok so right now I have something like this: ` app.post('/signin', function(req,res){
 firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(req.body.email, req.body.password)
  .catch(function(error) {
    // Handle Errors here.
    var errorCode = error.code;
    var errorMessage = error.message;
    // ...
    console.log(error)
    res.json("error")
 })

 firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
   if (user) {
    res.json(user)
   }
 });
})` , that doesn't seem right, how can I access the promise you're talking about?

Comment: OK, a simple .then() did the trick, thanks! Just one last thing, I have node as backend, so i do $ajax requests to my node script to get my database related stuff, and have JS scripts for each page, how/where would one implement a .onAuthStateChanged()?

Comment: @FábioSantos Sorry man, iOS developer here. Can't really help you with this frontend stuff :(